# golang not supporting struct slice depth with template

Tags: go, go-templates

I stuck with an unique problem. To learn golang, I created a twitter kind of website. It has tweets and each tweets can have comments and each comment can have sub-comments.

Showing struct pd in homepage.html

```
Env.Tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "homePage.html", pd)
```

where pd is pagedata (I removed extra information for simplicity)

```
type PageData struct {
    TweetView    []tweets.TweetView
 }
```

Where tweet.TweetView is

```
type TweetView struct {
    Tweet
    CV       []comments.Comment
}
```

where comments.Comment is

```
type Comment struct {
    TweetID         int64
    ParentCommentID int64
    CommentID       int64
    CreatedAt     time.Time
    Name          string
    UserID        int64
    CommentMsg string
}
```

This works. but if I change the CV in tweetView with comment.CommentView .. template stop showing TweetView.

comment.CommentView is

type CommentView struct {
    Comment
    CC []Comment
}

the new TweetView would be defined as

```
type TweetView struct {
        Tweet
        CV       []comments.CommentView
    }
```

Getting this error, when trying to make a datastore query to extract tweet object into Tweetview

```
err := datastore.Get(ctx, tweetKey, &tweetView[v])
```

> datastore: flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices: field
>   "CV",

I think it is a limitation of golang. What should I do?

Comment: What you are asking is definetely something you can do. There is something in your template: you should post some simplified version of it.

Comment: template has no issue because even when I dont use CV in template it doesnt show anything. But if I edit out that CV variable from TweetView . it works again .. {{range .TweetSlice}} {{range .CV}} hello {{end}} {{end}}

Comment: Are you sure the data you're passing is correct? (By the way, what is TweetSlice?). I think you should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @neclepsio - thanks for your response. This is a workable code.. it has 3 layers structure slices. In fact, even if I add  "test          []int" in comment structure.. it doesnt work. Please let me know where can I post my code? I am new in this

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. The problem was with datastore.Get query.

It was giving below error when I was running

```
err := datastore.Get(ctx, tweetKey, &tweetView[v])
```

> datastore: flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices: field
>   "CV",

So what I changed the query like this

```
var tweetTemp Tweet
datastore.Get(ctx, tweetKey, &tweetTemp)
tweetSlice[v].Tweet = tweetTemp
```

Please let me know if you see problem with this approach